# AppFuse 3.0 problems with sorting datatable

Tags: java, maven, jsf-2, primefaces

I use [AppFuse 3.0](http://appfuse.org/) to create the project with the follow command line:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-modular-jsf-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=3.0.0 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeRepository=http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse
```

Basicly is one multi-modular project in JSF .

After that I changed the datasource to Oracle (the initial project was using MySQL).

When run and list the users (.../admin/users), the sorting in UserList datatable not working why?

The code is:

```
                <p:dataTable id="users" var="user" value="#{userList.users}" sortBy="#{userList.sortColumn}"
                         paginator="true" rows="5"
                         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
                <p:column style="width: 25%" sortBy="username">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText value="#{text['user.username']}"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:commandLink action="#{userForm.edit}" value="#{user.username}">
                        <f:param name="id" value="#{user.id}"/>
                        <f:param name="from" value="list"/>
                    </h:commandLink>
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width: 34%" sortBy="fullName">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText value="#{text['activeUsers.fullName']}"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.fullName}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width: 25%" sortBy="fullName">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:column sortBy="email">
                            <h:outputText value="#{text['user.email']}"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputLink value="mailto:#{user.email}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.email}"/>
                    </h:outputLink>
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width: 16%" sortBy="enabled">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText value="#{text['user.enabled']}"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{user.enabled}" disabled="true"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

I need help ...

- appfuse.version -> 3.0.0
- bootstrap.version -> 3.0.2
- jsf.version -> 2.2.4
- primefaces.version -> 4.0

Comment: In the ManagedBean needed the users list (locally).

Comment: private List<User> users; is needed locally in Managed Bean.